# How to print contents from MySQL database to website using JSP and 3-tier architecture?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

I have an assignment that wants me to use 3-tier-architecture, which basically means the ui/presentation-tier can't speak directly with the database tier.

I get the connection to the database through a class called "ConnectionDB" that's part of the database package.

[Basic structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SF0R.png)

Say you want to create a webshop that shows the user some items that you have in your database, following this specific architecture, how is the right way to get the contents from the database into the JSP that displays them to the user?

Thanks.

Comment: MVC - Model, View, Controller.  You can just use Servlets for the Controlller, and JSP for the view.  Other frameworks exist like Struts and Spring.

Comment: Check this example https://www.javaguides.net/2019/01/jsp-jdbc-mysql-example.html

Comment: You gonna add what is called a `Data Access Layer` where you put your Database logic, and you use it in upper layer/s